# Django permission_required - how to detect if user has admin perm

Tags: django, model-view-controller

I want to ask and know, how to detect with decorator befero view method if user is admin.

Thanks.

Comment: do you mean `@staff_member_required`, i.e. has access to the django admin...?

Comment: thanks and would you know, how to redirect page to error 403? I have all in handlers and it is obviously works @staff_member_required(login_url='errors/403.html')

Comment: staff_member_required normally goes to the admin login page (which is usually what you want). Logging in by going to the 403 error page seems very unusual. Perhaps it would be better if you asked that as its own question with all the context needed to answer such a question..?